# Read List Items From Two Different Lists in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

#### Duplicate of

> [Read Data from 2 Lists into the Third List in MOSS 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670900/read-data-from-2-lists-into-the-third-list-in-moss-2007)

I have two custom lists displaying invoice data one for each state, my boss wants to have a third list which will have to read one (column)/listitem from each of the first two lists, I'm a newbie to SharePoint 2007, any tip as how to approach this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you delete this for us Pam?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your data model is wrong. Simpler would be to have a single list of Invoices, with a 'State' column. Then use 2 Views to display the records for each of the two states (filter by the value of the 'State' column).

And you could have a third 'All Invoices' that shows invoices for all states.

(You could even Group that 'All Invoices' view by State for boss-impressing goodness)

Alternatives can be done but might get a little complicated. If you have SharePoint Designer, the Dataview Web Part can merge data from multiple sources. [See this post about doing that.](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/11/17/merged-data-sources-for-the-dataview-web-part/)